# Modifying jParallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm working on a site [which can be seen here](http://homegrowndevelopment.com) and I just incorporated jParallax after following along [this tutorial](http://www.jquery4u.com/animation/jquery-parallax-tutorial/).  I was able to get everything to work, but instead of having the clouds follow my cursor, I want them to move in the opposite direction.  I would also like to slow the speed down to something more subtle.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Some code would help. Also: What have you tried so far?

Comment: All the code can be found on [my site](http://homegrowndevelopment.com/)

I'm assuming this is a mod that needs to take place in the .js file, but on a scale 1-10 on my js skills, I'm about a 2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to show some effort yourself. Go to the plugin page and read the documentation: http://stephband.info/jparallax/. What you are looking for are the options xparallax, and yparallax

```
$('#parallax .parallax-layer').parallax({
    mouseport: $('#parallax'),
    xparallax: -1,
    yparallax: -1
});
```

As for the speed change the dimensions of the images